# Does a hollow cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^3$ have corners in the manifold sense?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Does a hollow cylinder with end caps in $\mathbb{R}^3$ have corners? It is obvious that I need to check whether or not the edges are anywhere diffeomorphic to any open subset of the standard corner $[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$ in the (x,y) plane. I see that this doesn't seem to be the case, but an airtight proof escapes me.

Comment: Not corners, but not a manifold with smooth boundary either. You have a local picture of $\{(x,y,0): y\ge 0\}\cup \{(x,0,z): z\ge 0\}$. This is a product of a $1$-manifold with corner and $\Bbb R$.